Chromadb from_documents function giving error
The following function was working till a few days ago but now gives this error:
ValueError: Expected EmbeddingFunction._call_ to have the following signature: odict_keys(['self', 'input']), got odict_keys(['args', 'kwargs']) Please see https://docs.trychroma.com/embeddings for details of the EmbeddingFunction interface. Please note the recent change to the EmbeddingFunction interface: https://docs.trychroma.com/migration#migration-to-0416---november-7-2023
I am not sure what changes are necessary to work with this.
` def create_chromadb(link): 
    embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    loader = TextLoader(link)
    documents = loader.load()
    
    # Split the documents into chunks (no changes needed here)
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=500)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    
    # Update for new EmbeddingFunction definition
    # D is set to the type of documents (Text in this case)
    D = Union[str, List[str]]  # Adjust based on your document format (single string or list of strings)
    embedding_function: EmbeddingFunction[D] = embedding_function
    
    # Initialize Chroma with the embedding function and persist the database
    db = Chroma.from_documents(chunks, embedding_function, ids=None, collection_name="langchain", persist_directory="./chroma_db")
    db.persist()
    print(f"Saved {len(chunks)} chunks")
    
    return db`

docs.trychroma.com/migration#migration-to-0416---november-7-2023

I slightly modify your code, using HuggingFaceEmbeddings instead of SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embedding = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
db = Chroma.from_documents(
    documents=chunks,
    embedding=embedding,
    persist_directory="/tmp/chroma_db"
)
db.persist()

